# Is $\int \limits _{0}^{1}x^\alpha|ln(x)|^\beta dx$ convergent?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Is $\int \limits _{0}^{1}x^\alpha|ln(x)|^\beta dx$ convergent, where $\alpha >0, \beta >0$? Thanks .

Comment: I fear that if you don't [include some context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960), your question will be closed and probably deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, since the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality grants:
$$ \left(\int_{0}^{1}x^\alpha |\log x|^{\beta}\,dx\right)^2 \leq \frac{1}{2\alpha+1}\int_{0}^{+\infty} z^{2\beta}e^{-z}\,dz = \frac{\Gamma(2\beta+1)}{2\alpha+1}.$$
As a matter of fact,
$$ \int_{0}^{1}x^\alpha|\log x|^\beta\,dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty}z^{\beta}e^{-(\alpha+1)z}\,dz = \frac{\Gamma(\beta+1)}{(\alpha+1)^{\beta+1}}$$
through the same substitution as above, $x=e^{-z}$.

Comment: thanks but what do you mean by 
$$ \Gamma(2\beta+1)$$

Comment: @hichamgauss: the definition of the $\Gamma$ function is $$\Gamma(u)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}x^{u-1}e^{-x}\,dx $$ that is a clearly convergent integral for $u>0$.

Comment: thank you very much good job

Comment: @hichamgauss: you're welcome.

Comment: +1 This is good for more advanced readers, but the Gamma function might be a bit advanced for someone asking this question (just a guess). I have added a (hopefully) simpler answer that uses $\log(x)\lt x$ instead. In any case, this is a good demonstration of the usefulness of the Gamma function.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\log(x)\lt x$ for all $x\gt0$, it follows that, for $u\gt1$ and $\beta\gt0$,
$$
\frac1{2^\beta\beta^\beta}\log(u)^\beta=\log\left(u^{\frac1{2\beta}}\right)^\beta\lt\left(u^{\frac1{2\beta}}\right)^\beta=u^{\frac12}\tag{1}
$$
Using the substitution $x=\frac1u$ and $(1)$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1x^\alpha\left|\log(x)\right|^\beta\,\mathrm{d}x
&\le\int_0^1\left|\log(x)\right|^\beta\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_1^\infty\log(u)^\beta\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{u^2}\\
&\le2^\beta\beta^\beta\int_1^\infty u^{\frac12}\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{u^2}\\
&=2^\beta\beta^\beta\int_1^\infty u^{-\frac32}\,\mathrm{d}u\\[3pt]
&=2^{\beta+1}\beta^\beta\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$